# CDI: How to debug / inspect?

Tags: java, debugging, cdi, inspection

Since I'm new to CDI, I encounter strange behaviors now and then which I can't explain (cyclic injection until OOMError, Interceptor not invoked on some beans, etc).

Is there a (simple) way to print a tree of beans and dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dump this JSP in my test applications using openwebbeans

http://people.apache.org/~covener/debug.jsp

You could probably remove the openwebbeans-isms and still get a nice cheap little rundown of the beans.  The JSR299 API gives you access to far more than what's dumped here.

(posted without any kind of cleanup)